# How to change pandas column names using regex for this case?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with lots of column names with `[0][1]` string in them, I was wondering how to change them to `_01` and so on.

Here is my example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,20],'flux[0][0]':[1.1,1.2],
                   'flux[1][0]':[1.3,1.4],'ellip[2][0]':[1.5,1.6]})

print(df)
   flux[0][0]  flux[1][0]  ellip[2][0]  id
0         1.1         1.3         1.5  10
1         1.2         1.4         1.6  20
```

My try:

```py
df.columns = ['flux_00', 'flux_10', 'ellip_20', 'id']
print(df)
   flux_00  flux_10  ellip_20  id
0      1.1      1.3      1.5  10
1      1.2      1.4      1.6  20
```

But it takes too long for many columns. Is there any other simpler ways?

I am very new to pandas, so please be patient and kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the easiest:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,20],'flux[0][0]':[1.1,1.2],
                   'flux[1][0]':[1.3,1.4],'ellip[2][0]':[1.5,1.6]})


df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'(\w+)\[(\d+)\]\[(\d+)\]',
                                    lambda x: "{}_{}{}".format(
                                        x.group(1), x.group(2),x.group(3)) )

print(df)
```

Gives:

```
   ellip_20  flux_00  flux_10  id
0       1.5      1.1      1.3  10
1       1.6      1.2      1.4  20
```

Answer (score 4):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,20],'flux[0][0]':[1.1,1.2],
                   'flux[1][0]':[1.3,1.4],'flux[2][0]':[1.5,1.6]})

# Per comment, if you have column names other than 'flux...':
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(pat='\[', repl='_', n=1).str.replace(pat='\[|\]', repl='')
```

yields

```
   id  flux_00  flux_10  flux_20
0  10      1.1      1.3      1.5
1  20      1.2      1.4      1.6
```

Comment: There is not only `flux` there are so many other names such as `ellip[0][0]`, `id[0][0]`, and so on.

Comment: Just wondering, why did you choose the other answer over this one? @MilkyWay007

Comment: @Erfan This is an excellent answer and I have paid respect by upvoting it,  but it uses .str method twice and its slightly harder to remember. Another was selected as an answer since that one seems  more extensible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list expansion and a regex substition.
Something like:

```py
import re

regex = re.compile(r'([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\]\[([^\]]+)\]')

columns = [regex.sub(r'\g<1>_\g<2>\g<3>', col) for col in df.columns]

df.columns = columns
print(df)
```

```
   flux_00  flux_10  ellip_20  id
0      1.1      1.3      1.5  10
1      1.2      1.4      1.6  20
```

It leaves the string unchanged if the regex does not match, which is perfect as it will leaves column names like `id` unchanged.

However, in case you also have "one dimensional names", you can improve the regex by using nested and named group:

```py
regex = re.compile(r'([^\[]+)\[([^\]]+)\](\[(?P<third>[^\]]+)\])?')
columns = [regex.sub(r'\g<1>_\g<2>\g<third>', col) for col in df.columns]
# Works also with strings like "name[0]"
```